# How to get JSON Object as response from HTML server

Tags: java, android, html, json, android-networking

I'm sending a POST request from my android client app to the HTML server and the HTML page returns a JSON Object as response but with content-type="text/html".

In request, I'm passing 2 parameters: 1. image file 2. option value
As soon as the 'option' is selected, request is sent. And, I'm expecting a 'JSON Object' including a 'JSON Array' as response.

So, as I'm requesting to receive the JSON Object (if I'm using .getAsJSONObject), I'm getting a parse error-"org.json.JSONException: Value DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject".

If I'm using .getAsString so as to receive the response as text, I'm getting the respective 'DOCTYPE' HTML code of the webpage.
URL of the server page is: http://52.66.220.119:8088/

In this, select an face image file and select 'WoWCrown' option from the dropdown menu and hit on 'TRY' button. You'll get the JSON Object on HTML.

I've already used .getAsJSONObject() ; .getAsString() ; getAsJSONArray() and some other get methods of Fast Android Networking Library, but I can't get the JSON Object as response from the server. In some of them, I get parse error and in rest i get the  error as mentioned above.

```
// Inside OnItemSelectedListener()
JSONObject postObject = new JSONObject(  );
                RequestBody fbody = null;
                File file = null;
                try {
                    file = new File(imageUri.getPath());
                    Log.d( "hello file", file +"" );

                    fbody = RequestBody.create( MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
                    Log.d( "hello fbody",  fbody +"" );

                    postObject.put( "face", fbody);

                    Log.d("LIST POSITION", selectedIdSpinnerArrayList.get(position-1) );
                    Log.d("LIST NAME", spinnerArrayList.get( position ) );

                    postObject.put( "mylist", selectedIdSpinnerArrayList.get(position-1) );

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                AndroidNetworking.post( URL )
                        .addJSONObjectBody( postObject )
                        .setPriority( Priority.HIGH )
                        .setTag( "hello AN" )
                        .build()
                        .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse (JSONObject response){
                                Log.e("hello", response.toString());
                                //if (response != null)
                                {
                                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                                    Type type = new TypeToken<JSONObject>() {
                                    }.getType();
                                    JSONObject result = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), type);
                                    Log.d( "hello", result.toString() );
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError (ANError anError){
                                Log.d("hello GSON", anError.getLocalizedMessage() + anError.getCause());
                            }
                        });
```

Expected response is:-
JSON Object on POST request from the client android application.

Error:-

On using .getAsJSONObject() method --->
org.json.JSONException: Value DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

On using .getAsString() method --->
exact HTML code of the page.

[screenshot of the JSON Object is attached as link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1i1u4.png)

Comment: What is the expected json?

Comment: `exact HTML code of the page.` what does this mean? is the request returning JSON, or HTML?

Comment: It is returning HTML and the expected json is JSON Object. For more info, check the screenshot attached. U'll understand.

Comment: the screenshot is showing the rendered HTML, while not showing the whole response.

Comment: Then try this:- URL of the server page is: http://52.66.220.119:8088/

In this, select an face image file and select 'WoWCrown' option from the dropdown menu and hit on 'TRY' button. You'll get the JSON Object on HTML.

Comment: Does the content type of response requires to be application/json or not? Since it is showing content type="text/html" So, does the backend needs reworking or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: it returns a valid JSON. `.getAsString()` should work. Could you explain what exactly is wrong when you are using it?

Comment: If I'm using .getAsString(), I'm getting the HTML as response and not the JSON Object parsed in string format. Check using HTML Inspector that the content type in 'response headers' is showing 'text/html' and not 'application/json'. Check this in the screenshot.

Comment: Refer to this for RESPONSE, I made a document of problem I'm facing :- https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yvkFgwhL-5b4quB5nu1AyeXZsVXBBfJE8_Gt7zS0_QA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: if the string is a valid JSON, you can just create a JSONObject from it using `new JSONObject(yourString)`

Comment: how should I parse string into JSON Object since I'm receiving HTML page in String response. I would require JSON data as response in order to convert string data into json data.

Comment: the response is valid JSON data

Comment: Bro I'm getting HTML code in response, and not the JSON data. That's what my problem is. Although the HTML must respond me with the JSON data, instead I'm getting HTML page.

Comment: Ok, which `URL` are you posting to?

Comment: URL is:-  http://52.66.220.119:8088/

Comment: That is wrong URL, check the chrome's networking console - it posts to `http://52.66.220.119:8088/android_overlay`